# Does google provides any api for checking a website's search result position for particular keyword?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to write a program which will find a website's position in google search result. I am planning to make curl request and parse the search result till i get the result. It could have been easy of there is already a google api to find it.

So i would like to know if there is any google api foor it or not?

So finally guys, Since as per yous ideas no legal is found I have made myself a small one toll for my self:
it can be found in:
http://outsourcingnepal.com/PositionChecker/

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but have a look at this: [http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_12.php](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_12.php)

Comment: that's sounds good... but its not showing the correct result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no API for that. By design. And if you're going to do it programatically anyway (e.g. by using Curl to request Google search result pages) then there's is a good chance that Google will start throwing captchas at you, or even block you alltogether.

Google does not want scripts rummaging through their search results.

Comment: so what can be alternate solution for me?

Comment: There isn't one without violating Google's terms of service.

Comment: Interesting. So all those pagerank sites are bogus, breaking TOS, or what?

Comment: Yes, they are all breaking the ToS. That is why all these tools need frequent updating to keep working, because Google keeps changing things to head them off.